# Deleting queried documents from Azure's CosmosDB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a collection in CosmosDB that has a large number of JSON files. I have a python program that continuously writes and uploads data to that collection. My format of the data just changed, so I am now writing files with a new structure. I have to delete all the files in my collection with the old structure.

Question 1: Do the documents have a date of creation tag? If so, I would like to delete all the files that have a date of creation earlier than a specific date. How can I do that?

Question 2: If the answer to the previous question is no, there is a way I can query parts inside all the old files I want to delete. I cannot query the files entirely, but I can query what's inside of them. So is there a way to delete the entire documents based on the query of what's inside of them? Maybe if there is a way to retrieve all the document IDs that are used to respond to my query, then it would be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All documents have a property called `_ts` which is the unix timestamp of when the document was created and is auto populated by Cosmos. You should be able to query using this property to find all the documents created before a specific date.

Comment: One minor comment: `_ts` value will change if the document is updated. It essentially tells you when the document was created and/or last modified.

Comment: np, I"m glad that it helped